# Nokia Glance-like lock screen clock on Android

Tags: lock-screens

Is there any way to get Nokia Glance like power-saver clock + notifications on android phones with AMOLED screens?
It's very useful feature IMHO and does not consume much battery on phones with AMOLED screens.
I am not asking for app. It can be anything from an app to a ROM that has the feature.

**EDIT**
For those who don't know what Nokia Glance is:
It is a feature that shows digital clock when Lumia devices (and Nokia N9 if anyone still remembers the phone) with AMOLED screens are on stand by mode. The best thing is that it is ALWAYS there and you don't have to touch the screen or press a button for it to show up. It uses very less battery because it lights up only the necessary pixels with rest of the pixels turned off, something that is possible with AMOLED screens.
Here is a picture showing the feature in work:
[image]

Comment: Since there aren't many Nokia users here, it might help if you [edit] your question to describe what this feature does.

Comment: Besides, it would be a much better fit for [Software Recommendations](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), as "Is there an app for X" type questions are rather off-topic here (see our [help/on-topic]).

Comment: @Izzy: I am not asking for just an app. It can be anything ranging from an app to a ROM that has this feature. One could argue that it still is off-topic but I can't find a better place to ask this question. A similar question is unanswered on xda dev forums.

Comment: I understand. Still, strictly speaking both are not quite on-topic ;) OK, thanks to your update I can give you *indicators*. If I remember correctly, those features have been described with the *Moto X*. They *require* an Amoled display, or they'd drain your battery pretty fast (only with that display you can "turn on selected pixels only" while keeping the others inactive). There *are* apps emulating this on other devices I've read about; not having and Amoled, I "note them down" then...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The keyword is: "[Active Display](http://www.androidcentral.com/inside-moto-x-active-display)". Use that [in a search](http://www.appbrain.com/search?q=active-display) (a better custimized [Google Search here](https://www.google.com/search?q="active+display"+site%3Aplay.google.com)) turns up a whole lot of good candidates (oh, and a bunch of not-candidates, unfortunately). It might be useful ignoring the ones from Motorola itself, as they are probably intended for their device(s) (checking can't hurt, though). Just a few picks right from the first page:

[image: Active Display] [image: Battery Active Display]
<sup>[Active Display](http://www.appbrain.com/app/com.scheffsblend.activedisplay_ads) & [Battery Active Display](http://www.appbrain.com/app/com.edragone.batteryactive) are two examples of apps emulating Moto's *Active Display* on other devices</sup>

As I wrote, these are only the first two candidates picked up, and there are probably several more you might wish to check out for yourself. Good luck!

Comment: [Dynamic Notifications](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.greatbytes.activenotifications) is another good candidate.

Answer (score -1):

I use [Glance Plus](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.thsoft.glance). It does not consume much battery and has lots of options and very useful features like 'in pocket mode'. It lights up all pixels of the screen, but very dimly. I have used the app for a week, it appears to have made no difference to the amount of battery consumed

[image: Screenshot]

<sub>Click image for larger version</sub>

Comment: Please edit your answer to include more information, such as description, and screenshots. Your answer as it stands is not eligible to remain on this site.

Comment: Are you not affiliated to the linked app?